# How do I make flex box work in safari?

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

How do I make flex boxes work in Safari?
I have a responsive nav that uses a CSS flex box to be responsive
and for some reason it won't work in Safari.

Here is my code:

```css
#menu {
 clear: both;
 height: auto;
 font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Verdana;
 font-size: 1em;
 /*padding:10px;*/
 margin: 5px;
 display: -webkit-box; /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
 display: -moz-box;    /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
 display: -ms-flexbox;  /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
 display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Chrome */
 display: flex;         /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
 justify-content: center;
 -webkit-box-align: center;
 -webkit-flex-align: center;
 -ms-flex-align: center;
 -webkit-align-items: center;
 align-items: center;fffff
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400px;
}
#menu a:link {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100px;
 height: 50px;
 padding: 5px;
 background-color: yellow;
 /*border: 1px solid #cccccc;*/
 margin: 5px;
 display: flex;
 flex-grow: 1;
 align-items: center;
 text-align: center;
 justify-content: center;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #1689D6;
 font-size: 85%;
}
#menu a:visited {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100px;
 height: 50px;
 padding: 5px;
 background-color: yellow;
 /*border: 1px solid #cccccc;*/
 margin: 5px;
 display: flex;
 flex-grow: 1;
 align-items: center;
 text-align: center;
 justify-content: center;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #1689D6;
 font-size: 85%;
}
#menu a:hover {
 display: inline-block;
 color: #fff;
 width: 100px;
 height: 50px;
 padding: 5px;
 background-color: red;
 /*border: 1px solid #cccccc;*/
 margin: 5px;
 display: flex;
 flex-grow: 1;
 align-items: center;
 text-align: center;
 justify-content: center;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 85%;
}
#menu a:active {
 display: inline-block;
 color: #fff;
 width: 100px;
 height: 50px;
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-right: 5px;
 padding-left: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 background-color: red;
 /*border: 1px solid #cccccc;*/
 margin: 5px;
 display: flex;
 flex-grow: 1;
 align-items: center;
 text-align: center;
 justify-content: center;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 85%;
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu">
  <a href="#">Philadelphia</a>
  <!--<a href="#">Vacation Packages</a>-->
  <a href="#">United States of America</a>
  <a href="#">Philippines</a>
  <a href="#">Long Destinations Names</a>
  <a href="#">Some Destination</a>
  <a href="#">Australia</a>
</nav>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cyberjo50/n55xh/3/

Is there a prefix I'm missing to make it work in Safari?

Comment: what version of safari are you using? why is it nor working, what is it doing different? the more info you provide the better :)

Answer (score 43):

Giving flex a value solved the problem for me, e.g.

```
flex: 1 0 auto
```

Comment: Worked for me in March 2020.

Comment: In my case `flex: 0;` was giving 0 height to a `div`. I replaced it to `flex: 0 0 auto` and it worked. I remember this was a known bug, but I didn't find any reference online

Comment: This needs to be upvoted more, and be accepted as the answer, as there are tooo many posts proposing irrelevant solutions. October 2020 and this is still a thing. Thank you.

Comment: This is a correct and working fix from Feb' 2021.

Comment: Working for me - May 2021.

Answer (score 20):

I had to add the webkit prefix for safari (but **flex** not **flexbox**):

`display:-webkit-flex`

Comment: The OP *has* `display: -webkit-flex` already, I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: use `-webkit-flexbox` instead of `webkit-flex`. also use default flex. like that `display: flex; display: -webkit-flexbox;`

Answer (score 11):

Just tRy this

```
display: -webkit-box;   /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6, BB7 */
display: -ms-flexbox;  /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Safari 6.1+. iOS 7.1+, BB10 */
display: flex;         /* NEW, Spec - Firefox, Chrome, Opera */
```

this worked for me

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```css
select {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just try `-webkit-flexbox`. it's working for safari.
`webkit-flex` safari will not taking.

Comment: This answer is broad and confusing please consider revision.

Comment: i mean that safari will taking -webkit-flexbox instead of -webkit-flex. `display: flex; display: -webkit-flexbox;`

Comment: That helps, Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It works when you set the display value of your menu items from `display: inline-block;` to `display: block;`

See your updated code here:

```css
#menu {
    clear: both;
    height: auto;
    font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Verdana;
    font-size: 1em;
    /*padding:10px;*/
    margin: 5px;
    display: -webkit-box; /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    display: -moz-box;    /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
    display: -ms-flexbox;  /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Chrome */
    display: flex;         /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-flex-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;fffff
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400px;
}

#menu a:link {
    display: block; //here you need to change the display property
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: yellow;
    /*border: 1px solid #cccccc;*/
    margin: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #1689D6;
    font-size: 85%;
}
#menu a:visited {
    //no display property here                                                                       
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: yellow;
    /*border: 1px solid #cccccc;*/
    margin: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #1689D6;
    font-size: 85%;
}
#menu a:hover {
    //no display property here                                                                               
    color: #fff;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: red;
    /*border: 1px solid #cccccc;*/
    margin: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 85%;
}
#menu a:active {
    //no display property here                                                                               
    color: #fff;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: red;
    /*border: 1px solid #cccccc;*/
    margin: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 85%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would be useful

```
-webkit-justify-content: space-around;
```

Answer (score 0):

Demo -> https://jsfiddle.net/xdsuozxf/

Safari still requires the `-webkit-` prefix to use flexbox.

```css
.row{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col {
    background:red;
    border:1px solid black;

    -webkit-flex: 1 ;-ms-flex: 1 ;flex: 1 ;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      
    <div class="content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col medium">
                <div class="box">
                    work on safari browser 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col medium">
                <div class="box">
                    work on safari browser 
                    work on safari browser 
                    work on safari browser 
                    work on safari browser 
                    work on safari browser 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col medium">
                <div class="box">
                    work on safari browser 
                    work on safari browser 
                    work on safari browser 
                    work on safari browser 
                    work on safari browser 
                    work on safari browser  work on safari browser 
                    work on safari browser 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>   
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know if that's that still true in 2019?

Answer (score 0):

```
display: flex;
display: -webkit-box;
```

did it for me. Also there were two `display: flex;` on the same element from different classes. So I removed the other one.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue and tried almost all of the above solution.
Finally I tested with 3 simple Div and saw that it works without any problems.
So I concluded that there must be a problem with my child's elements and change display type to block and the problem was solved.

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
}
    
.child {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Autoprefixer, try this:

```
display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;        
    -webkit-box-pack: center;        
        -ms-flex-pack: center;        
            justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
```

And also remove the `#ffffff` from the code, here is the image pls check this

[image: here is the image pls check this]