# Why can I not style the text inside the button?

Tags: html, css, button

This is my button. My button is not centered, and I can't seem to edit the text inside.

[image]

Other postings suggest putting a span around the button's content, which I did, but it doesn't seem to work. I tried changing the letters to be pink just to see if it would do anything, but it did not. Presumably, here also would be where I could fidget with the placement inside the button, no? Here is my code.

```
<Button bgColor="#609D64" style={{ marginTop: '-17px' }}>
    <span style={{ color: 'pink' }}>START
    </span>
</Button>
```

Comment: Are you using a templating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the span. Try using flexbox.

I've added the styles

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

This should make the text centered both vertically and horizontally.

`<Button style={{ display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; text-align: center; color: pink; background: #609D64; }}>START</Button>`

btw it's not good to inline styles unless you really have to. also if this code doesn't fix you problem then please show what html Button outputs because it may be the rendered component is causing the problem.

Comment: But keep in mind, that older browsers won't support flexbox.

Comment: good point @D.Schaller. This could equally be achieved just using text-align center & padding

Comment: But what about safari does flex items works on safari, if works how?

Comment: using vendor prefixes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24899943/how-do-i-make-flex-box-work-in-safari

Answer (score 0):

It should work for you.

```
<Button style="margin-top:-17px; background-color:#609D64; text-align:center">
<span style="color:pink">START
</span>
</Button>
```

Comment: Yes it works css on span
Like 
Button span{
   color:pink;
   font-size:55px;
}

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution using flex. There is an `inline-flex` declaration –

```css
button {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #CDCDCD;
  background: #FFF;
  color: hotpink;
}
```

```html
<p><button>hello world</button> Welcome to the water planet!</p>
```

This is an especially important detail to know when mixing `flex` into `inline-block` layouts.