# Flex justify-content, align-items not working on Safari or mobile browsers

Tags: css, flexbox

I have images within a container element.  When the image height is less than the container height I want the image at the top of the container.  When the image width is less than the container width I want the image centered.
This is how I want it to look and it works on desktop Firefox and Chrome.
[image]

However, on desktop Safari and mobile Safari, Firefox and Chrome it looks like this with the shorter image centered vertically and the narrower width image stretched to fit the container width:
[image]

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.mainImageContainer {
  width: 500px;
  height: 375px;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.mainImageBtn {
  background-color: rgb(231, 60, 60);
  display: -webkit-box;   /* tried this did not work */
  display: -webkit-flex;  /* tried this did not work */
  display: -moz-box;      /* tried this did not work */
  display: -ms-flexbox;   /* tried this did not work */
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  height: 375px;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;    /* tried this did not work */
  -webkit-box-align: start;   /* tried this did not work */
  -webkit-flex-align: start;  /* tried this did not work */
  -ms-flex-align: start;      /* tried this did not work */
  -webkit-align-items: start; /* tried this did not work */
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.mainImage {
  cursor: zoom-in;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="mainImageContainer">
    <button class="mainImageBtn">
      <img class="mainImage" src="https://eoja82.github.io/For-Sale/img/car_2.jpg" alt="car"></img>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="mainImageContainer">
    <button class="mainImageBtn">
      <img class="mainImage" src="https://eoja82.github.io/For-Sale/img/tumbler%20-%202.jpeg" alt="instructions"></img>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I read this but none of the solutions worked for me: [How do I make flex box work in safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24899943/how-do-i-make-flex-box-work-in-safari).

I'm using the latest versions of the browsers.

Comment: Can you add in a couple of actual images to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I added the images.

Comment: Yea I see the issue, I guess the browser handles this part differently, but it looks like the problem is the button tag haha

Comment: Originally, I had just the img tag, but I was getting accessibility warnings from Gatsby about non-interactive elements having click events, so I wrapped the img in a button to get rid of the warning.

Comment: You can use an anchor element as well and make it `role="button"` and `href=#`. Must have href or else it's a violation for accessibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Safari has issues with flexbox on buttons. To work around this, wrap the contents of the `button` in a `div` and style the `div` instead.
2. Setting both axes of an image can result in the aspect ratio being ignored. Use `object-fit: contain` to ensure this doesn't happen.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.mainImageContainer {
  width: 500px;
  height: 375px;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.mainImageBtn {
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.mainImageWrapper {
  background-color: rgb(231, 60, 60);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 500px;
  height: 375px;
}

.mainImage {
  cursor: zoom-in;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: top center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="mainImageContainer">
    <button class="mainImageBtn">
      <div class="mainImageWrapper">
        <img class="mainImage" src="https://eoja82.github.io/For-Sale/img/car_2.jpg" alt="car" />
      </div>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="mainImageContainer">
    <button class="mainImageBtn">
      <div class="mainImageWrapper">
        <img class="mainImage" src="https://eoja82.github.io/For-Sale/img/tumbler%20-%202.jpeg" alt="instructions" />
      </div>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works as intended wrapping the ```img``` in a ```div``` without using ```object-fit``` and ```object-position```.  Would you still recommend using them "just in case" or leave it out if it works without it?

Comment: @eoja As long as you don't try to set the width of the image you should be okay, but there's no harm in using `object-fit` as a backup.